# CPP codes linking in VScode with Mingw-w64 in Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, header

I'm learning C++ with VScode with Mingw-w64 in Windows 10. 
Today, I watched how to make header files and build the separated codes in Visual Studio 2019. 
I wanted to implement this process in Visual Studio Code editor, but I met linking error.

My naive solution is like

```
~$ g++ -c .\main.cpp .\add.cpp 
~$ g++ .\main.o .\add.o -o test.exe
```

First, **compiling** the source codes into object files. 
Second, **linking** those object files to an execution file.

It works anyway, but when I tried to run the debugging mode, it doesn't work.
 
I think I need to edit **launch.json** file, but I have no idea...

The following images are about my situation.

[image]

[image]

How can I build those separated codes at once?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In this time, I just described the path of the definition code into 'tasks.json' file. 
After then, built the main code again, so that it worked.